# Unittest: filename with point not loaded properly

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-unittest, python-3.10

Setup: PyCharm, Python 3.10

We have the naming convention to name our python unittest files like an URL. For example: `my.domain.org.py`

In the past, this was no issue. Now after an IDE and Python Update it does not run anymore. Selecting right click -> Run "Python tests in my.domain.org.py" throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programs\Python\3.10.2\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my'
```

It seems, the loader is interpreting the "." in the filename as path.

How can I run the unittest without renaming the file (which solves the issue)?

Answer (score 1):

you cannot import python files with invalid names (in your case has dots in it) directly, but there's a turn around, you can use the imp library like (here in the example I have a function named `print_smth` that prints "it works!" in the `my.file.py`):

```
import imp

with open('my.file.py', 'rb') as fp:
    my_file = imp.load_module(
        'my_file', fp, 'my.file.py',
        ('.py', 'rb', imp.PY_SOURCE)
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_file.print_smth()
```

output:

```
test.py:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
it works!
```

**P.S: preferably DO NOT DO THAT! it is highly deprecated!**